# Auto scroll functionality in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I had added auto scroll functionality to my application by going through sample code.
In this code I'm getting  scroll from top to bottom and bottom to top. But I don't want to scroll from top to bottom . I always wants to scroll from bottom to top only. If I'm removing the topToBottom code and making changes to the remaining code according to that it is not working. Can any one help me.

```
-(void)viewdidLoad
{ 
    infoScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    infoScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,330,270);
    infoScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100,1000);
    [myInfoView addSubview:infoScrollView];

    scrollingToTop=NO;

    UIImageView *infoImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,0,200,1000)];
    infoImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lepke-tar2.png"];
    [infoScrollView addSubview:infoImgView];

    infoScrollView.delegate = self;
    if (infoScrollView.contentSize.height>infoScrollView.frame.size.height) 
    {
        [infoScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, infoScrollView.contentSize.height-infoScrollView.frame.size.height, infoScrollView.frame.size.width, infoScrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];

    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToTop) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    [myInfoView addSubview:infoScrollView];


    UIButton* infocancelBttn = [[UIButton alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(295,-8,45,45)];
    [infocancelBttn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infocancelBttn addTarget:self action:@selector(infoViewCloseAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myInfoView addSubview:infocancelBttn];
    [infocancelBttn release];


}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [infoScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, infoScrollView.frame.size.width, infoScrollView.frame.size.height+200) animated:YES];
}


- (void) scrollToTop
{
    scrollingToTop=YES;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
    //[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    [infoScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,-300)];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(scroll)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) scroll
{
    if (scrollingToTop==YES) 
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottom) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToTop) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }

}

- (void)scrollToBottom
{
    scrollingToTop=NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
    [infoScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,infoScrollView.contentSize.height-infoScrollView.frame.size.height)animated:NO];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(scroll)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your if-statement is wrong:

```
-(void) scroll
{
    if (scrollingToTop==YES) 
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottom) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
    else...
```

if you delete your scrollToBottom-method your code fails.
you should change this to 
            [self performSelector:@selector(**scrollToTop**) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
because you are asking if scrollingToTop is true